# Generating all words of length N from a given alphabet in Java

Tags: java, string, permutation, combinatorics

The cleanest way to generate all N - length words, with characters from a given alphabet , such that they must have in them a given character c.

If the length is 2, for an alphabet with this characters {a,b} , and the character is 'b' it should return a list like this:

> ab , ba , bb

So far I am thinking of using nested loops, but it's not clean, or using similar methods to permutation , to generate them all by increment the least significant bit and wrapping around when reaching last character from alphabet.

---

**EDIT**:

```
    ArrayList <String> data = new ArrayList <String>();
    int iterations = (int) Math.pow(alfabet.length, N);

    int  pos [] = new int [N];
    pos[N-1] = -1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < iterations;i++)
    {
        pos[N-1]++;
        for (int j = N-1; j >= 0;j--)
        {
            if (pos[j] == alfabet.length) 
            {
                pos[j] = 0;
                pos[j-1] ++;
            }
            else break;
        }
        String word = "";
        for (int j = 0 ; j < N; j++ )
        {
            word += alfabet[pos[j]];
        }
        int val = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < lst.length; j++)
        {
            if (word.contains(lst[j] + "")) val++;
        }
        if (val == lst.length) data.add(word);

    }
    return data;
```

This is the function i built, i made the alphabet static, for easier access through the code, and because i wont change it.
*Improved* on it a bit, and made it so that it doesnt check just a character, but a certain array of characters.
Would like a review of clarity, complexity or some things that i might have looked over.

Comment: seems like a recursive method could do.

Comment: It's good that you're thinking.  So what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: Try generating all the possibilities (that answer already exists, by the way ). Then loop and remove those that don't  contain the mentioned  character (very 
 clean and simple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't provide *any* Java code, I won't either ;) I don't want to spoil your fun...

A short, somewhat fast, non-recursive solution in *pseudocode* (aka, Swift) to get you going:

```swift
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]
let requiredChar = 2
```

```swift
func printAllWords() {
    var word = [0, 0]
    for _ in 0 ..< pow(alphabet.count, word.count) {
        if word.contains(requiredChar) { print(word) }
        for char in 0 ..< word.count {
            word[char] = (word[char] + 1) % alphabet.count
            if word[char] != 0 { break } // overflow
        }
    }
}
```

outputs the desired words:

> ca
>   cb
>   ac
>   bc
>   cc

This should run in **O(n.zⁿ)** time complexity, where:

- **n** is the *word* length;
- and **z** the *alphabet* length.

To play around with this code, [try this Swift sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5924ee6d85c3fe781a037f3f).

Getting a working Java version out of this should be straightforward. A [Kotlin](http://nilhcem.com/swift-is-like-kotlin/) version should be even easier... ;)

Comment: @dasdasd I did... but I like best my approach ;) It provides a shorter solution with much better readability. Nevertheless, not really clear which will perform better without further complexity analysis...

Comment: I cannot understand your approach and it does not seem a straight forward java approach. Can you provide one?